# Select all input elements that have a specific value and change their value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I dabble in Javascript for very basic tasks everyone now and then, but for the most part I'm basically a newbie. I have a page, which has multiple input elements, which all contain unique IDs, and I want to write a script that will find a collection of inputs that contain the same value, and apply a new value to all of those selected inputs. The script I have created can accomplish this by using getElementById, but this method is no good because all of my IDs are unique. I tried using getElementsByTagName('input').value, but that doesn't seem to work. The following is my code:

```
<input type="text" value="Original Value 1" id="input-1">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Original Value 1" id="input-2">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Original Value 2" id="input-3">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Original Value 2" id="input-4">

<script>
function change_input_value(){
var x = document.getElementById('input-1');
if(x.value = 'Original Value 1'){
x.value = 'New Value 1';
}
}

window.onload = change_input_value();
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to check the value when the page loaded or when the user changes the input as well?

Comment: You should try event delegation. A parent of all inputs listens for onchange. event.target will give you the element the user changed value in and e.target.value the current value. On this event compare the value with other inputs current value

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 problems:

- `getElementsByTagName('input')` returns an array like object, you need to iterate over it.
- You used the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`
- The last error is not causing an a problem but it should read `window.onload = change_input_value` instead, that assigns the `change_input_value` to the onload handler. You were calling `change_input_value()` and assigning its return (`undefined`) to `window.onload`. It worked because when your function was called, the HTML your function relied on was already rendered

```html
<input type="text" value="Original Value 1" id="input-1">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Original Value 1" id="input-2">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Original Value 2" id="input-3">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Original Value 2" id="input-4">

<script>
  function change_input_value() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (const input of inputs) {
      if (input.value == 'Original Value 1') {
        input.value = 'New Value 1';
      }
    }
  }

  change_input_value();
</script>
```

Comment: This is only half of the problem. ( ;-) )

Comment: Now I'm confused. That's what exactly what I meant...

Comment: @GerardvanHelden Yes, I was confused with your code and the OP's code :p Added that to the answer, explaining the 3 things the OP had done incorrectly. Thanks for the heads up, feel free to delete the comments now.

Answer (score 1):

You have confused the `=` (assignment) and the `==` (equality test) operators.

Also, attaching the eventhandler to `onload` in the way you do assigns the result of the call to the function as the `onload` handler. This is not what you want, you want the function to be executed as the handler:

Replace

```js
window.onload = foo(); // foo gets executed, return value is assigned
```

With

```js
window.onload = foo; // foo gets assigned to 'onload' property of 'window'
```

Or even better, use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

Comment: This is only the second half of the problem. User needs to iterate over the results of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

- Using `.querySelectorAll()` and the `input[value="Original Value 2"]` CSS selector which selects all `input` elements with the value "`Original Value 2`":

```js
function change_input_value() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="Original Value 2"]');
  x.forEach(function(e) {
    e.value = 'New Value 1';
  })
}
window.onload = change_input_value();
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Original Value 1" id="input-1">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Original Value 1" id="input-2">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Original Value 2" id="input-3">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Original Value 2" id="input-4">
```

Use `.forEach()` to loop through the NodeList.

- Selecting all inputs and checking the values correspondingly

```js
function change_input_value() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    let e = x[i];
    if (e.value == 'Original Value 2') {
      e.value = 'New Value 1';
    }
  }
}

window.onload = change_input_value();
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Original Value 1" id="input-1">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Original Value 1" id="input-2">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Original Value 2" id="input-3">
<br>
<input type="text" value="Original Value 2" id="input-4">
```

Comment: @LarsFlieger The first and original solution is not the best. The `[value="..."]` selector doesn't work if the value of the input has been modified after the HTML has been loaded, that's because the value attribute of the HTML doesn't stay in sync with the `input.value` property. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html#:~:text=The%20value%20property%20reflects%20the,from%20the%20HTML%20source%20code.

Comment: I think what @GerardvanHelden means is that this provides solutions without an English explanation of what the problem was.

Comment: @JuanMendes Didn't know that. Depending on what OP wants it's not useful than.

Comment: @LarsFlieger Beyond what the OP needs, we should strive for answers that help everyone, not just the OP.